# number_format add comma before last 2 digits issue

Tags: xml

Sample number:
36116

except result:
361,16 PLN

Steps:
`$price    = $dom->createElement('g:price', number_format($productPrice, 2, '.', ',').$productCurrency);`

wrong Result:
36,116.00 PLN

I have 2 types numbers: example 4826 then I need display: 48,26 or 75643 then I need display: 756,43 so always I need comma before last 2 digits

How to correct?

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:xml], but the content looks like [tag:php]. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the 2 to a 3, which specifies how many digits to have before the comma is inserted.

```php
    print(number_format(1000, 3, '.',','));
```

Outputs:
`1,000.00`

Comment: Can you please read again. I need always give comma before last 2 digits.  I have 2 types numbers: example 4826 then I need display: 48,26   or 75643 then I need display: 756,43 so always I need comma before last 2 digits